# Projectile motion: Results show big difference between the line with air resistance and the one without it

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, physics, projectile

I'm simulating the projectile motions with python on Spyder, one with air resistance and one without it. I started off by following [this exercise](https://share.cocalc.com/share/223c4e9ca1b913a9fa9d1d0f1028d90b7dc0b2d2/Week-06-Projectile/Week-06-projectile.ipynb?viewer=share).
It has guided me to do the projectile motion with air resistance. In order to make a comparison, I tried to plot a projectile motion without air resistance in the same graph with the same parameters on my own. However, the resulted graph has come as a surprise for me as it looks a bit off. There's a big difference between this two lines in terms of the range as the other similar graphs I've come across online only show a slight difference.

My graph:

[image]

(the smaller one is the one with drag while the bigger one is the one without it)

My questions are :

1. What caused this? Is it because the drag force I've put only includes drag coefficient and velocity, which made the graph smaller than the one that also has cross sectional area and rho included?
2. Is the way I'm doing it very complicated and how would you modify it to make it more efficient and neat?

It would be awesome if you're also willing to point out any errors I've made

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Model parameters
M = 1.0          # Mass of projectile in kg
g = 9.8          # Acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2)
V = 80           # Initial velocity in m/s
ang = 60.0       # Angle of initial velocity in degree
Cd = 0.005       # Drag coefficient
dt = 0.5         # time step in s

# Set up the lists to store variables
# Start by putting the initial velocities at t=0
t = [0]                         # list to keep track of time
vx = [V*np.cos(ang/180*np.pi)]  # list for velocity x and y components
vy = [V*np.sin(ang/180*np.pi)]

# parameters for the projectile motion without drag force
t1=0
vx_nodrag=V*np.cos(ang/180*np.pi)
vy_nodrag=V*np.sin(ang/180*np.pi)

while (t1 < 100):
    x_nodrag=vx_nodrag*t1
    y_nodrag=vy_nodrag*t1+(0.5*-9.8*t1**2)
    plt.ylim([0,500])
    plt.xlim([0,570])
    plt.scatter(x_nodrag, y_nodrag)
    print(x_nodrag,y_nodrag)
    t1=t1+dt

# Drag force
drag = Cd*V**2                      # drag force 

# Create the lists for acceleration components
ax = [-(drag*np.cos(ang/180*np.pi))/M]        
ay = [-g-(drag*np.sin(ang/180*np.pi)/M)]

# Use Euler method to update variables
counter = 0
while (counter < 100):
    t.append(t[counter]+dt)            # increment by dt and add to the list of time 
    vx.append(vx[counter]+dt*ax[counter])  
    vy.append(vy[counter]+dt*ay[counter])  

    # With the new velocity calculate the drag force
    vel = np.sqrt(vx[counter+1]**2 + vy[counter+1]**2)   
    drag = Cd*vel**2                                  
    ax.append(-(drag*np.cos(ang/180*np.pi))/M)    
    ay.append(-g-(drag*np.sin(ang/180*np.pi)/M))    
    
    # Increment the counter by 1
    counter = counter +1

x=[0]#creating a list for x
y=[0]#creating a list for y

counter1=0
while (counter1<50):

    #t.append(t[counter1]+dt),t already has a list.
    x.append(x[counter1]+dt*vx[counter1])    
    y.append(y[counter1]+dt*vy[counter1])  
    plt.ylim([0,500])
    plt.xlim([0,570])
    plt.plot(x,y)
    #print(x,y)
    counter1=1+counter1

# Let's plot the trajectory
plt.plot(x,y,'ro')
plt.ylabel("height")
plt.xlabel("range")
print("Range of projectile is {:3.1f} m".format(x[counter]))
```

Comment: The plots should be different, when you have air drag you're losing energy and the you should reach a shorter span. If you decrease the drag coefficient you see that each time you have a larger span. That being said, you have a bug in your code because you get a larger span with small drag coefficients than with no drag at all.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. How would you suggest me to fix the bug?

Comment: I don't know what the bug is. But maybe you could try using numpy arrays instead of lists. Also, you could wrap everything in a single loop. Also, it might be that reducing the step size you get better results.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you definitely have to include all parameters of the projectile as the total distance traveled is very sensitive to that.
2. Generally try to work with functions you can then call in for loops. This makes your code easier to read and more reusable. Implement for example a function which calculates a new time step. Also work with numpy arrays as vectors instead of having vx and vy separately.

Additionally there is an error in your calculations. When calculating the new velocities you also have to compute an updated angle. This is because in every step you have new angle (i.e. in the end of the flight the drag force in y direction has an opposite sign than gravity)

Do for example:

```
    vel = np.sqrt(vx[counter+1]**2 + vy[counter+1]**2)   
    drag = Cd*vel**2


    # calculate new angle for force separation
    a, v = np.array([1,0]), np.array([vx[counter+1], vy[counter+1]])
    if vy[counter+1] > 0:
        ang = np.arccos( np.dot(a,v) / (1*np.linalg.norm(v)) )
    else:
        ang = 2*np.pi - np.arccos( np.dot(a,v) / (1*np.linalg.norm(v)) )   

                           
    ax.append(-(drag*np.cos(ang))/M)    
    ay.append(-g-(drag*np.sin(ang)/M))
```